# GPS sentences offline parser for windows/linux plaform- free c code

Tags: parsing, gps, nmap

I want to add a GPS ability to my project: I want to record the GPS sentences while I drive and after that, to set the information I collected (mainly  cordination and timing information) in some kind of a data structure.

anyone knows a free c code available online on windows/linux for that?

Answer (score 1):

Most GPS receivers output the position information using the NMEA protocol, you need a NMEA parser written in C, take a look at [NMEA Library](http://nmea.sourceforge.net/) as an example.

The library contains a number of sample applications, probably the simplest to understand/implement is in the `nmealib\samples\parse` directory.

```
#include <nmea/nmea.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *buff[] = {
        "$GPRMC,173843,A,3349.896,N,11808.521,W,000.0,360.0,230108,013.4,E*69\r\n",
        "$GPGGA,111609.14,5001.27,N,3613.06,E,3,08,0.0,10.2,M,0.0,M,0.0,0000*70\r\n",
        "$GPGSV,2,1,08,01,05,005,80,02,05,050,80,03,05,095,80,04,05,140,80*7f\r\n",
        "$GPGSV,2,2,08,05,05,185,80,06,05,230,80,07,05,275,80,08,05,320,80*71\r\n",
        "$GPGSA,A,3,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,00,00,00,00,0.0,0.0,0.0*3a\r\n",
        "$GPRMC,111609.14,A,5001.27,N,3613.06,E,11.2,0.0,261206,0.0,E*50\r\n",
        "$GPVTG,217.5,T,208.8,M,000.00,N,000.01,K*4C\r\n"
    };

    int it;
    nmeaINFO info;
    nmeaPARSER parser;

    nmea_zero_INFO(&info);
    nmea_parser_init(&parser);

    for(it = 0; it < 6; ++it)
        nmea_parse(&parser, buff[it], (int)strlen(buff[it]), &info);

    nmea_parser_destroy(&parser);

    return 0;
}
```

When implementing with a GPS receiver, instead of passing the fixed strings (in `buff`) to the parser you just need to pass the received NMEA strings from the receiver to the parser.  The data gathered will be available in the `info` structure.

If you wish to develop your own parser, take a look [here](http://gpsd.berlios.de/NMEA.txt) for a detailed breakdown of the various messages that may be output from a GPS receiver.  Most GPS receivers output only RMC, GGA, GSA, GSV, GLL, VTG, and (rarely) ZDA.

Comment: thanks timrorr, It looks good but there is no documentation on how to use this library. Is anyone familiar with this code and can explain how to use it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Expanded the answer to explain how the library may be used.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can use the C library *libnmea* to parse NMEA sentences. It is really easy to use and easy to implement new sentence types if you find any missing.

[libnmea at GitHub](https://github.com/jacketizer/libnmea)

Clone the project:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jacketizer/libnmea.git
$ cd libnmea
```

Build it:

```
$ make && sudo make install && make unit-tests
```

Example code (*main.c*):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <nmea.h>
#include <nmea/gpgga.h>

int
main(void)
{
    // Sentence string to be parsed
    char *sentence = strdup("$GPGLL,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,225444,A\n\n");

    printf("Parsing NMEA sentence: %s", sentence);

    // Pointer to struct containing the parsed data. Should be freed manually.
    nmea_s *data;

    // Parse...
    data = nmea_parse(sentence, strlen(sentence), 0);

    if (NMEA_GPGGA == data->type) {
            nmea_gpgga_s *gpgga = (nmea_gpgga_s *) data;

            printf("GPGGA Sentence\n");
            printf("Number of satellites: %d\n", gpgga->n_satellites);
            printf("Altitude: %d %c\n", gpgga->altitude, gpgga->altitude_unit);
    }

    nmea_free(data);
    free(sentence);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with -lnmea:

```
$ gcc main.c -lnmea -o main
```